# How do I manipulate themes in React when printing?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have three buttons that have a white background and dark text. When one button is selected, the text turns light grey and the background turns blue. When printing, the background turns white, so the grey text is barely visible. I want to make the text darker when printing.

I know that @media print can be used with styled divs. Is there something similar for themes?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you can manipulate any CSS using @media print as you would with any other media rule, so you can apply any styles you want to the buttons using whatever selectors are used to apply their selected/de-selected appearances.